# How to convert hyper's Body stream into a Result<Vec<String>>?

Tags: rust, future, hyper

I'm updating code to the newest versions of hyper and futures, but everything I've tried misses implemented traits in some kind or another.

A not working example [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=29e503f3e41459425bf7166235e33916) for this ...

```
extern crate futures; // 0.3.5
extern crate hyper; // 0.13.6

use futures::{future, FutureExt, StreamExt, TryFutureExt, TryStreamExt};
use hyper::body;

fn get_body_as_vec<'a>(b: body::Body) -> future::BoxFuture<'a, Result<Vec<String>, hyper::Error>> {
    let f = b.and_then(|bytes| {
        let s = std::str::from_utf8(&bytes).expect("sends no utf-8");
        let mut lines: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
        for l in s.lines() {
            lines.push(l.to_string());
        }
        future::ok(lines)
    });

    Box::pin(f)
}
```

This produces the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `futures::stream::AndThen<hyper::Body, futures::future::Ready<std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>, hyper::Error>>, [closure@src/lib.rs:8:24: 15:6]>: futures::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     Box::pin(f)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `futures::stream::AndThen<hyper::Body, futures::future::Ready<std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>, hyper::Error>>, [closure@src/lib.rs:8:24: 15:6]>`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>, hyper::Error>> + std::marker::Send`
```

I'm unable to create a compatible future. `Body` is a stream and I can't find any "converter" function with the required traits implemented.

With hyper 0.12, I used `concat2()`.

Comment: You cannot use `and_then` from `StreamExt` over reference of a `Stream`.

Comment: StreamExt is up to now not used in this code. And the compiler has no problem with a reference of Body (which is no standard stream).

Comment: it looks like it comes from `TryStreamExt`, it is ok, what i meant is this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f80724daba44f75d1de13e420a28f485

Comment: Ah, ok. Missing copy trait. I've this fn only for this question. In my code I don't ref/move body around. I've changed it above.

Answer (score 2):

From the [reference of and_then](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.and_then):

> Note that this function consumes the receiving stream and returns a
> wrapped version of it.
>
> To process the entire stream and return a single future representing
> success or error, use `try_for_each` instead.

Yes your `f` is still a Stream, `try_for_each` will work as reference suggested but `try_fold` would be a better choice to represent bytes as lines in vector but as [@Shepmaster points in the comment;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993084/how-to-convert-hypers-body-stream-into-a-resultvecstring/63008584?noredirect=1#comment111445033_63008584) there is a possibility that if we directly convert chunks to the UTF-8 we can lose integrity of multi-byte characters from response.

Due to consistency of data, the easiest solution might be collecting all the bytes before conversion to UTF-8.

```rust
use futures::{future, FutureExt, TryStreamExt};
use hyper::body;

fn get_body_as_vec<'a>(b: body::Body) -> future::BoxFuture<'a, Result<Vec<String>>> {
    let f = b
        .try_fold(vec![], |mut vec, bytes| {
            vec.extend_from_slice(&bytes);
            future::ok(vec)
        })
        .map(|x| {
            Ok(std::str::from_utf8(&x?)?
                .lines()
                .map(ToString::to_string)
                .collect())
        });

    Box::pin(f)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=56be525f21339e47942d9f8b1b0547ab)

---

You can test the multiple chunk behavior by using `channel` from hyper Body. Here is I've created the line partition across the chunks scenario, this will work fine with the code above but if you directly process the chunks you will lose the consistency.

```rust
let (mut sender, body) = body::Body::channel();

tokio::spawn(async move {
    sender
        .send_data("Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5".into())
        .await;
    sender
        .send_data("next bytes of Line5\nLine6\nLine7\nLine8\n----".into())
        .await;
});

println!("{:?}", get_body_as_vec(body).await);
```

- [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9bd9d7ba6b1af28c4c7f6b9e2349774d) ( Success scenario )
- [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c01ae688df41ea0c9c58dfeec3a34fe5) ( Fail scenario: "next bytes of Line5" will be
  represented as new line in `Vec`)

---

**Note :** I've used `std::error:Error` as a return type since both `hyper::Error` and `FromUtf8Error` implement it, you may still use your `expect` strategy with `hyper::Error`.

Comment: Doesn't help me. This returns a Vec with one element holding the body as one String. The Result-Vec should have one element per line.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=54974bea36f5e107c76bbd3545d67747 the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `&std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`

Comment: This solution seems brittle — what if the returned data contains multibyte UTF-8 characters that are split across chunks of the body?

Comment: @Shepmaster Well I've focused the Future and Stream part but yes, we should collect all the chunks from stream into a vec before converting bytes to the UTF-8, thanks for the warning, I'll edit the code

Comment: A more efficient (but *way* more complicated) solution could probably take it chunk-by-chunk and keep some state around between calls, but I agree that getting all the data at once is the easiest way to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

I found two solutions, each of them is pretty simple:

```rust
/*
    WARNING for beginners!!! This use statement
    is important so we can later use .data() method!!!
*/
use hyper::body::{to_bytes, HttpBody};

// Takes only single chunk of data!
let my_vector: Vec<u8> = request.into_body().data().await.unwrap().unwrap().to_vec();

// Takes all data chunks, not just the first one:
let my_bytest = body::to_bytes(res.into_body()).await?;

let my_string = String::from_utf8(my_vector).unwrap();
```

This example doesn't handle errors properly, ensure your code does.